# Fixed indentation for sectioning commands

Tags: indentation, auctex

I'm looking for a particular LaTeX indentation feature regarding sections, subsections etc. Specifically, I would like to start the text within a section (assuming `\section` is the highest sectioning level) at column 4, in a subsection in column 6 etc., like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  some text not in a section: col 2

  \section{Second Section}
    Section text: col 4
    \subsection{First Subsection}
      Subsection text in col 6
      \begin{..}
        standard extra indentation for environments
      \end{..}

  \section{Last Section}
    Again some text in col 4

\end{document}
```

The other indentation rules should be unchanged (extra indentation for environments etc.)

Since `\section` is not an environment, I could not find anything in the AUCTeX customization. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I want the same thing, but I google for hours and get nothing, I really like the default indentation of TeXStudio, but the indentation of AucTeX is not eady to read.